# Overloading operator= or operator[] using const char* and/or string

Tags: c++, string, char, operator-overloading

I've been scouring google and stackoverflow for so-far no clear answer to this, so I'm asking directly...

I made a bitmap font class and I'd like to use an assignment operator: operator=(const char*) to assign a string literal to the text of the class.
Note: I'd also like to assign using string, string* and char*...
For example:

```
class BitmapText{
private:
    std::string _text;
public:
    void operator=(const char* _t){
        _text = _t;
    }
    /*I've also tried another iteration of this operator using
    BitmapText& operator=(const char* _t){
        _text = _t;
        return *this;
    }
    */
    BitmapText(){}
    ~BitmapText(){}
};


BitmapText* t1 = new BitmapText();
t1 = "Hello World"
```

Assigning the char string to the BitmapText object yields something like the following:

```
Assigning to 'BitmapText*' from 'const char[12]' incompatible type.
```

I'm sure there's a very good reason for this. But It can be done with the string class. I looked into the string class and it is typedef'd from:

```
typedef basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char> > string;
```

Is this why I can assign a char array to the string class? Because it somehow seems to inherit characteristics of char? Can I overload the way I'm trying without such a complicated implementation?

My second question is (I think) along the same lines:
I want to use the operator[](const char* _name) to return a child object who's name matches the _name value.

Every operator overloading example I look at uses right-hand operands of the same class type as the one being overloaded. I have read however, you can use different data types, and we can clearly use a char* to assign a value to a std::string object...

What am I missing?
Any and all help is so greatly appreciated.

Comment: WTF? `t1` is a pointer... You cannot overload operators for non-user-defined types, and pointers are not user-defined types.

Comment: You're forgetting to dereference `t1`. Try `*t1 = "Hello World";`

Comment: You probably want `BitmapText t1; t1 = "Hello World";`. Don't dynamically allocate stuff unless there's a real need to do that.

Comment: Thanks a bunch to everyone. BitmapText is just  a dumbed down version of the actual class. Pointers are actually necessary.  What about operator[](const char*)?

Comment: @Kerrek SB Thank you for your insight. I will endeavor to never miss any little detail again in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define the operator the following way

```
BitmapText & operator =( const std::string &t )
{
    _text = t;

    return *this;
}
```

It can be used for objects of type `std::string` and for objects of type `char *` because there is implicit conversion from `const char *` to `std::string` due to a conversion constructor of class `std::string`.

As for this code snippet

```
BitmapText* t1 = new BitmapText();
t1 = "Hello World"
^^^               ^^
```

then it has to be rewritten the following way

```
BitmapText* t1 = new BitmapText();
*t1 = "Hello World";
```

This statement

```
t1 = "Hello World";
```

is wrong because you are trying to assign a pointer of type `const char *` to a pointer of type `BitmapText *`.

Answer (score 4):

You're trying to assign to `t1`, which is not a `BitmapText` but a pointer to a `BitmapText`;

If you do `*t1 = "Hello World";` it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to assign to a pointer, the address of a string literal.
Instead try:

```
BitmapText* t1 = new BitmapText();
(*t1)= "Hello World";
```

Comment: The original operator is fine. Your suggested replacement is not. And if we're going to be pedantic, a single _ before a lower case letter is not reserved.

Comment: Why `(*t1)` rather than simply `t1`?

Comment: Readability, habit, and in some cases some compilers throw a warning (clang I think).

Comment: I don't believe the first and third. The second is up to you, of course.